# Div's align with header div above it and not the whole page

Tags: html, css, divider

So my page has a header div that has a width of 50%, I then want to position 3 div's below it but when doing so, I set the float to left for all of them and also set the width to 33%. The problem I'm having is that the boxes being created align with the header div and not the page. Below is the code and a picture of how the page is displaying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
        <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>

    <body class="header">
        <div class="div1">This is the header div that lies on the top of the webpage in fixed position.</div>
        <div class="blank-div"></div>
        <div align="center" class="float-left">CONTENT OF COLUMN ONE GOES HERE</div>
        <div align="center" class="float-left-middle-cell">CONTENT OF COLUMN TWO GOES HERE</div>
        <div align="center" class="float-left">CONTENT OF COLUMN THREE GOES HERE</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Then I have the css here

```
.header {
    width:50%;
    height:72px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float:center;
    position:fixed;
    display:block-inline;
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both;
}
.float-left {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    height:200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
.float-left-middle-cell {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:12.5%;
    margin-right:12.5%;
}
.blank-div {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
}
```

[This is a picture of the site so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71oOR.png) As you can see the divs are hugging the edges of the header.

Comment: your elements are all inheriting the css from <body>, which is causing real problems especially with regard to the margins.  The margins are what's causing the overflow of the three columns, as well as the overlap of the header <div1> element.  Get rid of the css in body, lose "position:fixed", and start applying styles to the actual elements.  Also, there's no "float:center"

Answer (score 0):

Your header class is assigned to your `<BODY>` tag, which means that the margins are added to your whole html body. So, there is no actual margins for your divs. And, since borders were added to the header, text in top rectangle was considered just text inside div, and the divs in next line are closer.
Secondly, as you have provided width for your middle div, next div has gone to the next line.

**Solution:** Remove or change values of your `float-left-middle-cell` class.

Then try to apply a border for div1 class and set margins for that.